# Convert string into date and compare to curent date

Tags: javascript, date, format

I am new to javascript.
I am trying to compare a date in a string with the curent javascript date.

```
function testDate() {
    var theTestDate = "21:36:40 30/02/2014";

    var xxx = new Date();

    var theTestDateNow = xxx.getHours() + ':' + xxx.getMinutes() + ':' + xxx.getSeconds() + ' ' + xxx.getDate() + '/' + (xxx.getMonth()+1) + '/' + xxx.getFullYear();
    if (theTestDateNow < theTestDate) {
        alert("New");
    }   else {
            alert ("old");
        }
}
testDate();
```

I tryed to format the current date to that string format, but now i think in need to format that strig so javascript can know that it is a date; and i dont know how.

Comment: Hope this was not a joke .. 30/02/2014 is not a valid date, and when parsed it gives something like 02 Mar 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to convert your test date, to Date object
(there are several ways to do it) and just compare them:

```
function testDate() {
    var theTestDate = "21:36:40 30/02/2014";
    var testDateObject = Date(Date.parse(theTestDate ));
    var now= new Date();


    if (testDateObject > now) {
        alert("New");
    } else {
        alert ("old");
    }
}
testDate();
```

[Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) works with nicely formated date string
[Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) standard constructor: Date(year, month-1, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

EDIT: with some further research the best way to parse string to date is to use custom function and adapt it to your particular case:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var parts = str.match(/\d+/g); //extract group of digits
    return new Date(parts[5],parts[4]-1,parts[3],parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);

}
var my_date = parseDate('21:36:40 15/02/2014');
var now= new Date();
alert( (my_date > now) ? 'New':'Old');
```

Comment: Have you tested this? testDateObject is not the date that is intended by theTestDate.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the date info you want using a regular expression:

```
var theTestDate = "21:36:40 30/02/2014";

var data = theTestDate.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,4})/);
// OR: if you are certain that your date always contains 2 digits for hours, 4 digits for year, ...
var data = theTestDate.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/);

var date = new Date(
    data[6], // year
    data[5] - 1, // month, 0 based index
    data[4], // day
    data[1], // hours
    data[2], // minutes
    data[3] // seconds
);
```

Basically, (\d{1,2}) will match 1 or 2 digits, and the total regex will match a string in your date format. Read more about regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and do it like this:

```
if (moment(theTestDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') > moment(curdate))
```

or if you are using the [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library then you can try like this:

```
if (Date.parse(theTestDate) > Date.parse(curdate))
```